# Checking domain position in google organic search results

Tags: php, search, xpath

I am using `php XPath` to parse.

How to get only `Organic Search Results` in google?

I tried..

```
// Grab the Google page using the chosen keywords
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('https://www.google.com/search?q='.$keywords.'&num=100&gl=us');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);

// Store the domains to nodes
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@class]/cite[@class]');
```

but i am getting empty result.

I also tried `//cite[@class]` but not getting expected result.

Need help.

Comment: I believe Google loads in results via JS and AJAX nowadays so your loadHtmlFile will return the basic google page with no results. You'd need something that would bring you the page back after javascript has run to do this.

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks. So i need to look for.. ? can you please tell me more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works for me.

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[1]/div[@class='kv']/cite");
```

It excludes `inorganic results` while parsing.